# Cannot read property 'reload' of null using firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I need to reload current user to update emailVerfied status. However At first login or  signup of user. The app return an error that  `Cannot read property 'reload' of null` when A user press triggers `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()`. However If I refresh the reload the app the reload function works fine. I need to trigger reload at a user action right after a user logged in. I am already using `onAuthChanged` and through this observer the `currentUser` exists and a console.log does print out the current user. However, at initial login after the console statement of authStatedChanged  `reload()` function is stating null for the current User.

Answer (score 2):

`firebase.currentUser.reload()` should be `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` Also make sure the currentUser is ready (after onAuthStateChanged listener triggers).

Comment: I'm calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()`. How do I make sure current user is ready?  I console.log the returned `user` from the authStateChanged function and then trigger the reload manually by a tap. Again the error occurs the first time a user is logged in or signed up